# Python threads and global variables

Tags: python, tkinter, global

I have a class with some variables declared as globals in the first method. Another subsequent method starts a thread, and the problem is that python doesn't recognize those global variables after t.start(). Here is how the program works:
1) user can click "YES"-button on tkinter window
2) program then starts to upload data into database. This step takes a while (2-5 minutes) and to prevent UI from freezing during the upload, the program starts a thread that performs the sql stuff. At same time, the program clears widgets from the window and replaces them with new widgets (a progress bar and a text field).
3) after upload is completed, the program again refresh the tkinter window with new buttons and a scrollbox.

Here is the code snippet:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
      #do some init here..

    def initUI(self):
        global text1, text2, button_no, button_yes, progress_bar #here are the globals
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame1.pack()
        text1 = tk.Label(self, text="Do you want to upload a new log file?", background="white")
        button_yes = tk.Button(self, text="YES", command=self.removeButtonYes)
        button_no = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=self.removeButtonNo)
        text1.pack()
        button_yes.pack()
        button_no.pack()
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def removeButtonNo(self):
#do something here

    def removeButtonYes(self):
        text1.pack_forget() #first three lines clear those original three widgets
        button_no.pack_forget()
        button_yes.pack_forget()
#then add some text with the progress bar
        text2 = tk.Label(self, text="Transferring data. Please wait...", background="white")
        text2.pack()
        progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=100, mode="indeterminate")
        progress_bar.pack()
        progress_bar.start(100)
        #initialize a thread to prevent the UI from freezing during sql inserts
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.writeLogtoDatabase)
        t.start()

    def writeLogtoDatabase(self):
        #open db connection, upload data and close db
        self.clearUI() #call a method to clear the progress bar and info text

    def clearUI(self):     
        text2.pack_forget()
        progress_bar.pack_forget()
```

It just throws following error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\test\testdb2.py", line 94, in writeLogtoDatabase
    self.clearUI()
  File "C:\Python27\test\testdb2.py", line 98, in clearUI
    text2.pack_forget()
NameError: global name 'text2' is not defined
```

Why? As you can see, I can call those variables outside the method where they are declared. Has this something to do with threading - a thing, that I am not very familiar with?

Unless I don't forget those text2 and progress bar widgets, they will show up in the last window which is not desired functionality.

Comment: Using global variables with threads can be very dangerous, you need to make sure to lock the variable before any change and release it after (unless it's read-only), you should really consider using [Queue](http://lonelycode.com/2011/02/04/python-threading-and-queues-and-why-its-awesome/), you can also refer to the docs [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue)

Answer (score 2):

You should add `global text2` on the `removeButtonYes` method (and also for `progress_bar`, otherwise you'll have the same problem again). It's completely useless to add a `global text2` statement in a function that doesn't define that variable.

Also I don't see the advantage of using a global variable in this case, except that it's really easy to create bugs. Why don't you simply use an instance attribute `self.text2` and `self.progress_bar`?

Answer (score 0):

the `global` statement does not create a global. It simply means that assignments to the given names are to assigned in the global context, not the local context. It also means a name access will get a global variable, rather than a local variable. if you only access a global variable then python is able to figure out the variable is a global rather than a local without the need for a `global` statement.

eg.

```
def adder(to_add):
    global total
    total = total + to_add
    return total

try:
    # total does not exist at this point
    adder(1)
except NameError as e:
    print(e)

total = 10
print(adder(4))
```

Your problem is that you declared a `text2` to be global, but then did not assign to `text2`, so the name `text2` was never created in the global context

When you later methods assign to `text2` they create the name in the method's local context (since `text2` is not declared to be global there). One the method ends, the `Label` object is dereferenced and garbage collected.

You really have no need to be using globals though. You have an instance of `Application` (called `self` in your methods) which you can assign your objects to. It's really easy to access these objects outside of your `Application` instance if you need to

eg.

```
app = Application() # assigns some object to text2 on self
app.text2.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you for clarify that global thing. I tested by adding global text2, progress_bar into method removeButtonYes(). This crashed python when executing. Could you please explain more how can I call those instance attributes (self.text2 and self.progress_bar) in this case?

Comment: How did python crash? What was the exception? Was it `NameError` or `AttributeError`? I think though, iIn `initUI` you should create all the UI elements you need and assign them to self eg. `self.text2 = Label(...)`. If you are getting a different exception then you should ask another question about the problem.

Comment: Tkinter window with progress bar just frozen and then Windows7 said that python.exe is not responding. Actually exactly the same phenomenon occured when I declared those UI elements in the `initUI()` and tried to access them in the `clearUI()`. I also tried to call `self.destroy()` in the `clearUI()`, but it clears the widgets that are added in step 3 (in separate method).

Comment: That is a separate question on how to use tkinter. Please ask post it as a fresh question.